# Significance of `[...] & wait $!`

Tags: bash, shell-script

What is the significance of the bash pattern `[...] & wait $!`? For example:

```
curl -LsS $AZP_AGENT_PACKAGE_LATEST_URL | tar -xz & wait $!
```

I understand this as:

1. The `&` instructs bash to run the prior pipeline in a background subshell.
2. The `wait $!` then waits for the pipeline to finish before returning.

But if that's the case, how is it any different from just running the pipeline itself? What's the point?

The script containing this example (and a few other instances) can be found at:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

Comment: Probably written by someone who typically uses another language where you fork off and wait. They just copied that idiom to Bash without thinking. You see that sort of thing all the time with other idioms (e.g., people asking how to loop over all the lines in a file and do something instead of just using `sed` or similar on the file directly, because looping over the lines is what they'd do in Python or C)

Comment: It seems to be unnecessary & I think user @muru is right ; but one vague use might be like this :: When you want to monitor these Scripts, some other script can check "ps" output , see the "wait" command and say that "Script is waiting for long running commands" , else it can either say "all ok" or "Script stuck" , based on some "Progress Indicators" !

Comment: @Prem, though `wait` is (and has to be) a builtin command, so you can't see it in the output of `ps`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two side effects of running a command asynchronously in a non-interactive shell that make `A` and `A & wait "$!"` different:

- SIGINT and SIGQUIT are ignored for `A`. If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, whilst running `bash -c 'sleep 1000 & wait "$!"'`, you'll notice `bash` is terminated, but not `sleep`.
- `A`'s stdin is redirected to `/dev/null`:

  ```
  $ bash -c 'readlink /dev/fd/0'
  /dev/pts/4
  $ bash -c 'readlink /dev/fd/0 & wait "$!"'
  /dev/null
  ```

Another difference is that in `A | B & wait "$!"` (where `$!` contains the pid of the process eventually running `B`), the exit status of `A` is lost (`$PIPESTATUS` will contain only one entry, the exit status of `wait`, which will be that of `B` if the `pipefail` option is not set).

In `zsh`, in `A | B`, `zsh` waits for both `A` and `B`, but in `A | B & wait $!` only waits for `B` (and the exit status of `A` is lost even with `pipefail`).

Another difference is that if a signal is delivered to the shell, it will be handled straight away and `wait` will return (even if the process it's waiting for is not finished).

Compare:

```
$ bash -c 'trap "echo Ouch" TERM; sleep 10 & wait "$!"; echo "$?"' & sleep 1; kill "$!"
[1] 13749
Ouch
143
```

Where `Ouch` is output as soon as `SIGTERM` is sent to `bash` (and `sleep 10` carries on running after `bash` terminates) with:

```
$ bash -c 'trap "echo Ouch" TERM; sleep 10; echo "$?"' & sleep 1; kill "$!"
[1] 13822
$ Ouch                                                                                                                                        6:11
0

[1]  + done       bash -c 'trap "echo Ouch" TERM; sleep 10; echo "$?"'
```

Where `Ouch` is output only after `sleep 10` returns.

Whether any of those side effects were wanted by the script author is another matter. You'll notice many other mistakes in that script, it's very well possible that whoever wrote that script didn't know much about shell scripting.